# Recursive function call in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a recursive function call in VBA (excel) that creates a scripting dictionary of ALL the employees in the organisation structure (direct and indirect).

The function **Get_Underling_Staff_IDs** has and input parameter of staff_ID of type double that is the database ID/ the employee's number. The function should return a scripting dictionary where each element is an employee number (double).

I'm having trouble getting the function to run in a recursive manor that allows it to navigate in one call from the calling routine from anywhere in the organisation structure to the bottom.

so far I have the following:

```
Function Get_Underling_Staff_IDs(MANAGER_ID As Double) As Scripting.Dictionary

' an instance of a single staff id that DIRECTLY reports to the MANAGER
Dim Direct_Underling_Staff              As Variant
' A dictionary of all the staff id's that DIRECTLY report to the MANAGER
Dim All_Direct_Underling_Staff          As Scripting.Dictionary

' an instance of a single staff id that INDIRECTLY reports to the MANAGER
Dim Indirect_Underling_Staff            As Variant
' A dictionary of all the staff id's that INDIRECTLY report to the MANAGER
Dim All_Indirect_Underling_Staff        As Scripting.Dictionary


Set Get_Underling_Staff_IDs = New Scripting.Dictionary

' Get a dictionary of all the employees that directly report to the MANAGER_ID
Set All_Direct_Underling_Staff = Get_Relation_Staff_Manager(MANAGER_ID)

For Each Direct_Underling_Staff In All_Direct_Underling_Staff

    If Not Get_Underling_Staff_IDs.Exists(Direct_Underling_Staff) Then
        Get_Underling_Staff_IDs.Add Direct_Underling_Staff, Direct_Underling_Staff
    End If

Next Direct_Underling_Staff

For Each Direct_Underling_Staff In Get_Underling_Staff_IDs

    ' Get All the Employees that indirectly report to the MANAGER_ID
    Set All_Indirect_Underling_Staff = Get_Relation_Staff_Manager(CDbl(Direct_Underling_Staff))

    If Not Get_Underling_Staff_IDs.Exists(Indirect_Underling_Staff) Then
        Get_Underling_Staff_IDs.Add Indirect_Underling_Staff, Indirect_Underling_Staff
    End If

Next Direct_Underling_Staff


End Function
```

Where am I going wrong with this?

Staff ID's are 5 digits long: eg 55707

the "MANAGER" is the boss of the boss of the indirect staff. (The boss' boss)

Thank you for your help.

Kind regards
Jordan

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Function Get_Team_Staff_IDs(MANAGER_ID As Double, _
         Optional dictAll As Scripting.dictionary) As Scripting.dictionary

    Dim dictDirect As Scripting.dictionary, k

    If dictAll Is Nothing Then
        'First call does not have a dictionary argument,
        '  so create a new one to hold the id's
        Set dictAll = New Scripting.dictionary
    End If

    Set dictDirect = Get_Direct_Reports(MANAGER_ID)
    For Each k In dictDirect
        'add this report
        If Not dictAll.Exists(k) Then dictAll.Add k, k
        'see if this report has their own reports
        Get_Team_Staff_IDs CDbl(k), dictAll
    Next k

    'Return the final set of id's to the
    '  original caller (was called as a function)
    Set Get_Team_Staff_IDs = dictAll

End Function
```